# (FragmentDirections Class), GameFragmentDirections(In this case) not generated while using safe args

Tags: android, android-fragments, kotlin, android-jetpack-navigation, android-safe-args

I am trying to navingate from GameFragment to GameWonFragment using Safe Args. But GameFragmentDirections class didn't generated.

```
 <fragment
    android:id="@+id/gameFragment"
    android:name="com.example.trivia.GameFragment"
    android:label="@string/android_trivia"
    tools:layout="@layout/fragment_game"
    >
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_gameWonFragment"
        app:destination="@id/gameWonFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/gameFragment"
        app:popUpToInclusive="true" />
    <action
        android:id="@+id/action_gameFragment_to_gameOverFragment"
        app:destination="@id/gameOverFragment"
        app:popUpTo="@id/gameFragment" />
</fragment>
```

**Project Module Gradle**

```
navigation_version = "2.3.0-alpha04"
classpath "androidx.navigation:navigation-safe-args-gradle-plugin:$navigation_version"
```

**App Gradle**

```
apply plugin: "androidx.navigation.safeargs"
```

Comment: Did you build the project? They are only generated when you build the project.

Comment: yes i rebuild and clean